# SQL Script cursor, variable and NPoco

Tags: sql, sql-server, npoco

I have an SQL script that contains variables declared as `DECLARE @@var_1 as bigint` and it contains a while loop as `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS`
Now executing such script using NPoco raises exception to `Must declare the scalar variable "@FETCH_STATUS".`
How can I resolve it? The main purpose is to use same script in both SQL Server and ORACLE.

```
DECLARE @@LayerId bigint;
DECLARE @@DId as bigint;
DECLARE @@DataSegment as CURSOR;
DECLARE @@IterationNo as int;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'DataSegment') IS NOT NULL AND
   OBJECT_ID(N'Layer') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @@IterationNo = 0;
    SET @@DataSegment = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT Id FROM DataSegment  

    OPEN @@DataSegment;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @@DataSegment INTO @@DId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET  @@IterationNo = @@IterationNo + 1;
        SET  @@LayerId = 9;
        PRINT @@LayerId;


    --Insert parent RouteVersion
        INSERT INTO Layer Values(@@LayerId,'Migration',6,'Trace',
        'Route','TEST', @@DId, NULL, @@LayerId, 9)   
             Print 'Iter is ' ;
        Print @@IterationNo

     --fetch next
         FETCH NEXT FROM @@DataSegment INTO @@DId;
    END
    CLOSE @@DataSegment;
    DEALLOCATE @@DataSegment;

END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you mentin your code here

Comment: @MansiChaudhari check now.

Comment: Try `@@Fetch_Status` instead.

Comment: Ignore my previous. I don't see where you are using a variable `@FETCH_STATUS` with one single `@`. Is this the whole code?

Comment: By the way, why do you use `@@` for your variables? Do you need them to be GLOBAL?

Comment: datasegment is your table or what

Comment: Let me try to clarify :)
Yes datasegment is a table
I am using @@ to escape '@' as I am executing this script in C# using NPoco and I want this script to be executable in both SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: If you need to escape @ characters, you should use @@@@FETCH_STATUS to refer to a global variable, oder was?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @LayerId bigint;
DECLARE @DId as bigint;
DECLARE @DataSegment as CURSOR;
DECLARE @IterationNo as int;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'DataSegment') IS NOT NULL AND
   OBJECT_ID(N'Layer') IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
SET @IterationNo = 0;
SET @DataSegment = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT ID FROM DataSegment    

OPEN @DataSegment
FETCH NEXT FROM @DataSegment INTO @DId

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET  @IterationNo = @IterationNo + 1;
    SET  @LayerId = 9;
    PRINT @LayerId;


Insert parent RouteVersion
    INSERT INTO Layer Values(@LayerId,'Migration',6,'Trace',
    'Route','TEST', @DId, NULL, @LayerId, 9)   
         Print 'Iter is ' ;
    Print @IterationNo

     FETCH NEXT FROM @DataSegment INTO @DId;
END
CLOSE @DataSegment;
DEALLOCATE @DataSegment;
END
```

OR

Change your .net connection setting as

Database=db;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=pass;Allow User Variables=True

and then try your own code

Comment: With this I get an exception `Parameter '@LayerId' specified but none of the passed arguments have a property with this name`

Comment: is '@layerid' autoincrement?

Comment: if yes then dont pass it if no then pass some value to @LayerId at the time of declaration

Comment: `@layerid` not not autoincrement. I am not passing any argument to this script.
I tried initializing at the time of declaration but still getring same exception.

Comment: PetaPoco does support named parameters. That's why this error exists

Comment: Change your .NET connector settings as:                                 Database=db;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=pass;Allow User Variables=True                                                                                          then try your own code it will work

Answer (score 0):

For system arguments use @@@ instead of @@

```
DECLARE @LayerId bigint;
DECLARE @DId as bigint;
DECLARE @DataSegment as CURSOR;
DECLARE @IterationNo as int;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'DataSegment') IS NOT NULL AND
   OBJECT_ID(N'Layer') IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
SET @IterationNo = 0;
SET @DataSegment = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT ID FROM DataSegment    

OPEN @DataSegment
FETCH NEXT FROM @DataSegment INTO @DId

WHILE (@@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET  @IterationNo = @IterationNo + 1;
    SET  @LayerId = 9;
    PRINT @LayerId;


Insert parent RouteVersion
    INSERT INTO Layer Values(@LayerId,'Migration',6,'Trace',
    'Route','TEST', @DId, NULL, @LayerId, 9)   
         Print 'Iter is ' ;
    Print @IterationNo

     FETCH NEXT FROM @DataSegment INTO @DId;
END
CLOSE @DataSegment;
DEALLOCATE @DataSegment;
END
```